# How to build a unicode string with emojis in c#?

Tags: c#, unicode, asp.net-core-3.1, emoji

I've been using the following code to translate unicode parts that are taken from a text file in a format of string array `["1F3F3", "FE0F", "200D", "1F308"]`. The mentioned unicode parts are a sample of ️‍ emoji and are taken from [unicode.org](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html) resource(#1553 on the page).

```
    public static void PrintEmoji(params string[] unicodeParts)
    {
        var unicodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var unicodePart in unicodeParts)
        {
            unicodeBuilder.Append((char) Convert.ToInt32(unicodePart, 16));
        }
        if(unicodeBuilder.ToString() is var unicodeResult && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unicodeResult))
            Console.WriteLine(unicodeResult);
    }
```

But this code only works for UTF-16 code units, for example  (U+1F600), and not for unicode code part. How should i modify my method to be able to work with unicode code parts as well?

Comment: [Emoji under the hood](https://tonsky.me/blog/emoji/)

Comment: I can't remember exact `c#` syntax so I hope that the following .NET/PowerShell example could help: `(("1F3F3", "FE0F", "200D", "1F308") | ForEach-Object { [char]::ConvertFromUtf32([Convert]::ToInt32($_, 16))}) -join ''` returns `️‍`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz), the following solution seems to work fine.

```
public static void PrintEmoji(params string[] unicodeParts)
{
    var unicodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var unicodePart in unicodeParts)
    {
        unicodeBuilder.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(unicodePart,16)));
    }
    if(unicodeBuilder.ToString() is var unicodeResult && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unicodeResult))
        Console.WriteLine(unicodeResult);
}
```