# System.Drawing - DrawString text with emoji

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I just want to create an image which contains some text. This text can contain emojis.
I'm using the "Segoe UI Emoji" font, and call:

```
var fontName = "Segoe UI Emoji";
var font = new Font(fontName, 48, FontStyle.Regular);
var textFormat = new StringFormat
{
  Trimming = StringTrimming.None
};
graphics.DrawString(" some text ", font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(80, 400, width - 160, height - 460), textFormat);
```

then the emojis are black and white in the resulting image...
How could I render them in color?

Comment: [Suggested Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66853430/1070452)  nd [another relevant past post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74528302/1070452)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question...

Comment: That's not possible.  The text rendering engine used by System.Drawing does not have that feature.  It requires a more modern one, based on DirectWrite and OpenType font support.

Comment: Do you know a library with such support?